# Errors in minor details in a class output

Tags: python, class, account

I have two files :

```
class Account:
def __init__(self,id=0,balance=100.0,AIR=0.0):
    self.__id = id
    self.__balance = balance
    self.__AIR = AIR
def getd(self):
    return self.__id
def getbalance(self):
    return self.__balance
def getAnnualInterest(self):
    return self.__AIR
def setid(self,newid):
    self.__id = newid
def setbalance(self,newbalance):
    self.__balance = newbalance
def setAnnualInterestRate(self,newrate):
    self.__AIR = newrate
def getMonthlyInterestRate(self):
    return self.__AIR/12
def getMonthlyInterest(self):
    return self.__balance*self.getMonthlyInterestRate()

def withdraw(self,amount):
    if amount<=self.__balance:
        self.__balance -= amount
def deposit(self,amount):
    self.__balance += amount
def __str__(self):
    return "Account ID : {0.setid} Account Balance : {0.setbalance} Annual Interest Rate : {0.setAnnualInterestRate}".format(self)
```

and  Test:

```
   from Account import Account
def main():
    accountA = Account(0,100,0)
    accountA.setid = 1234
    accountA.setbalance = 20500
    accountA.setAnnualInterestRate = 0.375
    print(accountA)
    accountA.withdraw(500)
    accountA.deposit(1500)
    print(accountA)
    print(accountA.getMonthlyInterest())
main()
```

My output  is mostly correct  but there are two minor deatils which I have gotten wrong and I am not sure where in the code the problem is from.

Account ID : 1234 Account Balance : 20500 Annual Interest Rate : 0.375
Account ID : 1234 Account Balance : 20500(**This is supposed to be 21500)** Annual Interest Rate : 0.375
0.0(**And this is supposed to be 671.875 but somehow I got it wrong**)

Comment: self.__balance does not change as deposit and withdraw are called. I'm new to python myself, so I'm not sure about variables within classes, but this seems to be where the problem comes from.

Comment: Why your string format call the setters methods (setid,setbalance...)

Comment: self.getbalance() yields the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

`accountA.setbalance = 20500` doesn't call the `setbalance` method. It *changes* the value of the `setbalance` attribute *to* 20500 (that is, after this line, `accountA.setbalance` is no longer a method but an int). Instead, you want `accountA.setbalance(20500)`.

However, what you're doing is profoundly un-pythonic in the first place (you're a Java/C#/C++ programmer, aren't you?). Getters and setters are an anti-pattern in Python: just access and change the `id`, `balance` et al. attributes, and make them properties if (and *only* if) you need to perform computations/checks when setting/accessing them.

In addition, `__attribute` is *not* a private attribute in Python. The pythonic way to mark an attribute as "private" is a *single* leading underscore. However, it's just a convention, and the attribute itself will still be public (everything always is in Python -- it has no concept of visibility modifiers).

Comment: I mostly dabble in C++. Not really familiar in python.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
accountA.setid = 1234
accountA.setbalance = 20500
accountA.setAnnualInterestRate = 0.375
```

doesn't call the functions. You actually change functions into variables this way. To call the functions use this notation:

```
accountA.setid(1234)
accountA.setbalance(20500)
accountA.setAnnualInterestRate(0.375)
```